# How to use QProcess?

Tags: qt, qgis, qprocess

I want to open a project of QGIS from a QProcess object.
If I am under console I must type

```
qgis --project /path/of/my/qgis/project/nameofproject.qgs
```

Then, I do the next:

```
QString app="qgis";
QStringList arguments;
arguments.append ("--project /path/of/my/qgis/project/nameofproject.qgs");
```

And then I call it in this way:

```
proceso->start(app,arguments);
```

But I have this error in the call:

*Cannot find /home/david/Programacion/Qt/SQL/Sql2/build-prueba2-Desktop_Qt_5_3_GCC_64bit-Debug/--project /home/david/GIS/CRCC.qgs*

where:
***/home/david/Programacion/Qt/SQL/Sql2/build-prueba2-Desktop_Qt_5_3_GCC_64bit-Debug/***  is the path of my Qt application and

***--project /home/david/GIS/CRCC.qgs*** is the path I set in the arguments QStringList

I don know how must I set the QProcess object for avoid the path of my app.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try this in the following ways. [With a single command](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start-3):

```
const QString command( "qgis --project /path/of/my/qgis/project/nameofproject.qgs" );

QProcess process;
process.start( command );
```

Or [with arguments](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start):

```
const QString program( "qgis" );
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "--project";
arguments << "/path/of/my/qgis/project/nameofproject.qgs";

QProcess process;
process.start( program, arguments );
```